# When applying a bandpass filter designed in Matlab's DSP system toolbox, is it necessary to do any normalization?

Tags: matlab, filtering, bandpass

I'm applying the next bandpass filter to the data of an impulse response coming from .wav; it fades data below 10 Hz and above 400 Hz:

```
d = fdesign.bandpass('N,Fst1,Fp1,Fp2,Fst2,C',...
                117,9.99,10,400,400.01,10000);
d.Stopband1Constrained = true;
d.Astop1 = 60;
d.Stopband2Constrained = true;
d.Astop2 = 60;

Hd = design(d,'equiripple');    % Passband type
h = fvtool(Hd);    % Filter design plot
```

Whose plot is:
[image]

Original signal vs. filtered signal looks like this:
[image]

Resulting signal is pretty much different from original, so I took a look into frequency domain:
[image]

As you can see, magnitude order is notoriously smaller in the bottom plot than the top one in this second plot. Considering the first picture, at least for around 200 Hz resulting amplitude might be almost equal to the original one but it doesn't happen (regardless of the amplitude increase after 300 Hz).

Is something missing in my design that causes this differences? Do I have to do any normalization to get an amplitude after filtering similar to the original one? Using 117 as filter's order is the best option to minimize fading.
Thank you in advance for you help.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you are cutting a lot of signal frequencies in the transition from 10Hz to 200Hz (look the attenuation in the frequency response of the filter), consider to use lowpass filter or to change filter prototype to someone with faster transition.
By cut definition each frequency that is attenuated more than -3dB is cut.